# Problem with Record type pseudocode, display last column of every row

Tags: pseudocode

I have problem creating pseudocode for this case:
'Each row has different amount of columns, my task is to display last column of each row'

```
type Row is record
Integer: ColumnsAmount
Columns is array [1..ColumnsAmount) of Integer

type Chart is record
Integer: RowsAmount
rows is array [1..RowsAmount) of Row

Chart: tab
```

For sure it has to be a loop from 1 to RowsAmount and in the loop: display tab[ColumnsAmount] (displays last column)

Here's my attempt:

```
for f:=1..RowsAmount step 1{

   display(tab[f].tab[ColumnsAmount]) **<-- PROBLEM IN THIS PART**
 }
}
```

For reference theres another task that is correct (I am aiming to do something similar above):
'Write pseudocode which will display every car owned by each company'

```
type Company is record
 String: name
 Integer: CarAmount
 car is array[1..CarAmount] of Car
end

type Car is record
 String: name
end

data is array[1..10] of Company
```

Correct Pseudocode for this case:

```
for f:=1..10 step 1{
 for a:=1..data[f].CarAmount step 1{
   display(data[f].car[a].name)
 }
}
```

How can I do something similar in rows/columns case?

Answer (score 0):

Create the hierarchy for the identifiers used (indicating arrays with `[]`). Keeping in mind that `ColumnsAmount` may only occur once for each row, but there are several rows. To identify the correct `ColumnsAmount`, it is necessary to include the complete reference. These are the references:

```
tab
  rows[]
    ColumnsAmount

tab
  rows[]
    Columns[]
```

Fill in the the subscripts used, including the first as the subscript to the second:

```
tab
  rows[f]
    ColumnsAmount

tab
  rows[f]
    Columns[tab.rows[f].ColumnsAmount]
```

Then write the code:

```
for f:=1..RowsAmount step 1 {
    display(tab.rows[f].Columns[tab.rows[f].ColumnsAmount])
}
```

Or, you might consider separating the nested reference (it is easier on the eyes):

```
for f:=1..RowsAmount step 1 {
    a:=tab.rows[f].ColumnsAmount
    display(tab.rows[f].Columns[a])
}
```

---

The same applies for the referenced example, also with two references to consider.  `CarAmount` occurs 10 times, so a complete reference is necessary to identify which `CarAmount`:

```
data[]
  CarAmount

data[]
  car[]
    name
```

Add the subscripts:

```
data[f]
  CarAmount

data[f]
  car[a]
    name
```

Then the code:

```
for f:=1..10 step 1 {
  for a:=1..data[f].CarAmount step 1 {
    display(data[f].car[a].name)
  }
}
```